# Check for value of selector by find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I want to get the value of the "*tabindex*" selector of this HTML code:

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$placeContent$placeTopContent$filter$textAccount" type="text" value="110111102" id="ctl00_ctl00_placeContent_placeTopContent_filter_textAccount" style="width: 130px;" data-kpxc-id="ctl00_ctl00_placeContent_placeTopContent_filter_textAccount" tabindex="-1">
```

I tried with it with the following code, but I only get the value of "*value*". How can I correctly check for it?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*['@id="ctl00_ctl00_placeContent_placeTopContent_filter_textAccount" and @tabindex]').get_attribute('value')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute `tabindex` and following code.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="ctl00_ctl00_placeContent_placeTopContent_filter_textAccount"]').get_attribute('tabindex')
```

You can also use css selector.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ctl00_placeContent_placeTopContent_filter_textAccount').get_attribute('tabindex')
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!